# Cannot add new SQL data tables in Visual Studio 2012 PRO

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-express

Don't  know what happened but for some reason MS Visual Studio is no longer letting me to add or edit tables in Sever Explorer. When I right click on the "Tables" the only options I got are; refresh and properties. I tried re-installing MS Visual Studio and SQL Express Server but still having that same problem. Have no idea what else to do. I'm logged in as an Administrator on my computer.

IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpgNL.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [`SQL Server Data Tools`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/tools.aspx). I had the same problem and the option apppeared after I installed SQL Server Data Tools.